# How to fix html tooltip taking in no styles?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Working with html tooltip and applying styles to the tooltip class, the styles are being applied checking with developer tools, but ain't getting visible in the page.

I've tried my code running in w3schools and it's working. Tried changing values in DevTools and it's still the same in my local.

```html
<h4>
I am 
<input type=number>
years old 
<span class= "tooltip">Some Text</span>, my annual income old <br> 
is 
<input type=number> 
and I have saved <br> 
<input type=number class= "numbers"> 
<span class="sub">(pre-tax or tax-exempt)</span>
and 
<input type=number> <span>(taxed).</span>
</h4>
```

And the styles applied are:

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative !important;
    border: 2px solid black !important;
    height: 100px;
    background: red !important;
    width: 100px;
}
```

And this is what I'm getting. The backgroud color as well the border is not visible but it's there in the source.

[image: The Result]

Comment: Try `background-color` instead of just color.

Comment: I have actually used ```background``` and also tried with ```background-color```, and it's still the same.

Comment: I tested your code and it's working fine.

Comment: Yes it does work with different platforms. I think some styles are overriding mine, in my environment. But no other styles are being listed in the devtools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved changing the class tootip to some other name, as my styles were overridden by previously written styles in the environment.